# data is not saving properly in memory stream C#

Tags: c#, file-io, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack and saving an html document in MemoryStream :

```
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
       HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
       doc.load(path);
       . 
       .
       doc.Save(ms);
```

Now the problem is that sometime the document saved fully and sometimes some contents of the document ( from end ) lost, it did`nt save with the document. Can anybody tell me why this is happening and how can i solve this?

Comment: Please post a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add after saving this

```
memoryStream.Seek(0, System.IO.SeekOrigin.Begin)
```

Answer (score -1):

When working with streams (or anything that implements IDisposible for that matter), make sure you manage your memory efficiently. .Net Garbage collection can kick in at any time, and results can be unpredictable.

This is sometimes as easy as wrapping your variable in a using() statement:

```
        using(var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            var doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.Load(path);
            doc.Save(ms);
        }
```

Comment: GC can kick in any time; but the results won't affect the posted code.  GC only collects objects that are no longer used.  "ms" won't be collected until after the call to save, at the earliest--which wouldn't not cause any problems like the OP described.

Comment: Right you are - I suppose I'm just clutching at straws :)